# Angular 4 | how can i set a timer and will update my API data?

Tags: angular, api, timer

How can i set timer that will update my API data when the countdown is done, and will back to original countdown when the API data is updated.

Example i want to count to 10 and after that my API data will be updated and so on.

Below is my code with timer.

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, Pipe, PipeTransform, VERSION  } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response, RequestOptions, Headers } from '@angular/http';
import { SlicePipe, DatePipe } from '@angular/common';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable'
import 'rxjs/add/observable/timer'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/take'

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
})

export class AppComponent{

public data: any;
countDown;
counter = 10;

constructor( private http: Http ) {
    this.countDown = Observable.timer(0,1000)
  .take(this.counter)
  .map(() => --this.counter);
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getVoicepicData();
    this.getData(); 
    console.log('hi');
}

getData(){
    let headers = new Headers({
        'token': "MY TOKEN GOES HERE",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    let options: RequestOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

    return this.http.get('http://my.apidatahere.com/api/', options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
}

getVoicepicData() {
    this.getData().subscribe(data => {
        this.data = data
    })
}
}
```

Comment: What is the issue with current code?

Comment: theres no issue with current code, but i dont know how to implement my timer method to update my API data when the countdown hits to 0 and it will resume back when the API data is updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use set interval method in Javascript to trigger any function at the interval n seconds and you can stop the timer by clear Interval.

```
apiTimer : any
    ngOnInit() {
    this.getVoicepicData();
   this.apiTimer= setInterval(() => {
              this.getData()
            }, (this.counter*1000));
}
```

call the below line whenever you want to stop the timer. If you missed to call clearInterval, API will be triggered continously after every n seconds

```
clearInterval(this.apiTimer);
```

Comment: thanks for this, i just want to refresh my API Data every 60 seconds. i use your code but its not working for me.

Comment: change the timer to 6000, since setInterval accepts time in milliseconds. also put console inside setinterval function and check.

Comment: this one? Observable.timer(0,1000) or the counter = 10; ? it seems its updating my data every 1 milisecs.

Comment: in setInterval, this.counter*1000 = 10*1000 = 10000 milliseconds

Comment: got it man, thanks. one last thing. how can i reset back my timer in counter 10 when the countdown is done?

Comment: call clearInterval(this.apiTimer) to stop the timer. If you want to call the API only once, stop the timer before calling getData method. You can also see setTimer if you want to call the method only once after n seconds. upvote and make this as correct answer if it's working

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like :

```
alive = true;

constructor(private appTest : AppTestService) {

    // start calling your api every 10 secs
    Observable.timer(0,10000)
    .takeWhile(() => this.alive) // only fires when component is alive
    .subscribe(() => {
        this.appTest.getData().subscribe(data=> {
           console.log(data);
        })
    });

}

ngOnDestroy(){
    this.alive = false; // switches your Observable off
}
```

Here is the working demo of that, please have a look :

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-interval-observable

Comment: this works clean and simple. one last thing before my app completely works. how can i async this with my timer? lets says i have and actual clock ticking every 10 seconds? and will async my countdown timer to update my API data?

Comment: @JydonMah, so didn't get you?

Comment: it works fine with me, but i want to sync my timer with your code for visibility purposes. i want a visual countdown so i can see the realtime ticking of my timer. ill add some screenshoots of my interface

Comment: okay then I suggest you create another function with setInterval , which updates you time eventually, but dont mix it with this one.

Comment: ahh so this code works only in takeWhile because it only accepts boolean value and not number am i right? anyways, this works fine with me :)

Comment: @JydonMah, this will also work with you suggesting , but that will make your code bit complex, I am just suggesting to keep code seprate. Will you please accept and upvote the answer ?